# All gym exercises at home

Tags: strength-training, home-exercise, machine

I have the following things:

1. Dumbbells (to which weight plates can be added or removed)
2. A barbell
3. A pull up bar
4. A resisitance band
5. A horizontal bench like furniture

I don't have any machines which are there at the gym.

If I absorb knowledge about strength training (online), equivalent to the level of a gym trainer, would I be able to train all my muscles with the things I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking if what you have at home is enough to train all your muscles?

Well, yes.

Actually, I would strongly argue that you could train all your muscles with either dumbbells, a barbell OR a pull up bar (with other bodyweight exercises).

Resistance bands are a nice addition, but not a necessity, and likewise the bench, it's nice to have, but you don't need it.

You definitely don't need the myriad of machines they have in commercial gyms, I've seen people get in astoundingly good shape with just a couple of kettlebells.

The real "secret" is to start doing something and keep at it. Find a good program and run with it, there are a lot of free programs online for either dumbbells, barbells, bodyweight or a combination of them. Pick one and stick with it for at least 6 months, preferably at least a year, then re-assess and see if you think you need to change.

Comment: This and so much this - "The real "secret" is to start doing something and keep at it.".

Comment: The name for this is dumbbar, workouts you only do with dumbbells and barbells. I would recommend a bench which you can get for as cheap as ~$50 with a barbell rack personally, as floor presses and other alternatives dont quite match a dumbbell/barbell bench press.